# Can't pass variable to views style plugin template

Tags: views, 8, theming, plugins

How do I pass a variable to a twig template from a preprocess function of a views style plugin in a custom module?

In `alpha.module`, I have tried:

```
function alpha_preprocess_views_view(&$variables) {
  $variables["beta"] = "1";
}
```

and

```
function alpha_preprocess_page(&$variables) {
  $variables["beta"] = "1";
}
```

The template file is `alpha-gamma.html.twig` and the plugin is `Gamma.php`:

```
/**
* Style plugin.
*
* @ViewsStyle(
*   id = "gamma",
*   title = @Translation("Gamma"),
*   help = @Translation("Displays gamma."),
*   theme = "alpha_gamma",
*   display_types = {"normal"}
* )
*/
class Gamma extends StylePluginBase {
...
}
```

The template file is invoked and renders its output on the view's row results. However, `{{ beta }}` yields no result in the same file. I know I'm missing something important, but none of the examples I've found are specific to this type of row style template.

Guidance would be appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In below code you preprocess the variables for `views-view.html.twig` file

```
function alpha_preprocess_views_view(&$variables) {
  $variables["beta"] = "1";
}
```

and, `function alpha_preprocess_page(&$variables)` will preprocess the variables for `page.html.twig`

So, if you create a file views-view.html.twig then you will get your variable `{{ beta }}`

Comment: Based on the direction provided in your answer, and after a cache clear, the solution is `function alpha_preprocess_alpha_gamma(&$variables) {`. Thanks!